# Stack overflow Exception in solving QuickSort algorithm

Tags: java, quicksort, stack-overflow

I'm trying to implement the QuickSort Algorithm in Java. But whenever I run the code it gives me a runtime exception of StackOverFlowException. I just can't seem to figure out why my boundaries are messing up. Here's the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class QuickSortOne
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int a[], n;

    Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);

    n = sn.nextInt();
    a = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        a[i] = sn.nextInt();
    }

    QuickSort(a, 0, n-1);


    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        System.out.println(a[i] + " ");

}

public static void QuickSort(int a[], int l, int r)
{
    if (l < r) //Checking for Base Case
    {
        int p = Partition(a, l, r);
        QuickSort(a, l, p);
        QuickSort(a, p+1, r);
    }
}

public static int Partition(int a[], int l, int r)
{
    int p = a[l];
    int i = l+1;
    for (int j = l+1; j <= r; j++)
        if (a[j] < p)
        {
            int temp = a[j];
            a[j] = p;
            p = temp;
            i++;
        }
    int temp = a[i-1];
    a[i-1] = p;
    p = temp;
    return i;
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking strangers to spot errors in your code by inspection is not productive.  You should identify (or at least isolate) the problem by using a debugger or print statements, and then come back with a more specific question (once you've narrowed it down to a 10-line [test-case](http://sscce.org)).

Comment: Well, have you tried adding diagnostics to find the values of `l` and `r` on each recursion?

Comment: I'd be curious to see the value returned by Partition.  method names, by the way, should be camelcase and start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: There wasn't a problem with the boundary conditions, I figured out that I made silly mistakes in the variables.

Comment: If this is homework, you should mark it with the [homework] tag.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to return i from inside the for loop of your Partition method.  It'll never iterate more than once.

Answer (score 0):

You should review your sources for this algorithm, as your partition method bears little resemblance to the traditional partition method.

You're definitely trying to partition in place, so you might want to look at the [in-place version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#In-place_version) of this on Wikipedia, and try to do what's described there.

Additionally, once you get your partition working, the pivot should be in place and its index can be skipped in the recursive calls, which your recursion is not doing.